# Counting unique values in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I'm having trouble with an SQL question.
I have two tables: personals and patient treatments.
The personal table has the the information of the personals, and the treatments table has the personal ID and the patient ID who received the treatment.
I need to find the personal who gave the most treatments to **different** patients.
I have tried the following:

```
   SELECT ID , First_Name , Last_Name
   FROM Personal JOIN Patients_Treatments ON ID = Personal_id 
   GROUP BY ID , First_Name , Last_Name
   HAVING COUNT(*) >= ALL (SELECT COUNT(Personal_id) FROM Patients_Treatments 
   GROUP BY Personal_id)
```

The problem is that it gives the personal who gave the most treatments, not the one who gave the most treatments to different patients. 
Thank you for your time !

EDIT:
Found a solution if anyone is interested:

```
SELECT Personal.ID,First_Name,Last_Name
FROM Personal,Patients_Treatments
WHERE Personal.id = Patients_Treatments.Personal_id
GROUP BY Personal.ID,First_Name,Last_Name
HAVING COUNT(distinct Patient_ID) >= all(SELECT COUNT(distinct Patient_ID) 
FROM [Patients_Treatments] GROUP BY Personal_id)
```

Comment: soooo, mysql or SQL Server?

Comment: Sorry miss clicked, SQL Server

Answer (score 3):

This will return the personal(s) with highest treatments.

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES ID , First_Name , Last_Name
FROM Personal JOIN Patients_Treatments ON ID = Personal_id 
GROUP BY ID , First_Name , Last_Name
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT Patient_ID) DESC
```

Comment: I upvoted you, but you need to change the `COUNT(DISTINCT Personal_id)` for `COUNT(DISTINCT Personal_Id) DESC`

Comment: @Lamak gotcha :)

Comment: Doesn't work,  I think that because you counted how many times the personal ID appeared with DISTINCT , which is 1. Any way I found a solution but thank you for the effort :)

Comment: You are right it should be `ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT patient_id) DESC`. BTW: Don't use style joins.